# How can I display the title of my Google WebApp from a cell in my spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to display javascript output in google webapp (without using the sheet ID)?

I'm working on a webapp and I want the title of the webapp to come from cell A1 on my spreadsheet.  I want to make copies of the spreadsheet later on and I don't want to have to edit the code every time. I just want to be able to deploy it. This is what I have so far....

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("form")
}


function getTitle() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    const titleSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sign-In")

    const sheetTitle= titleSheet.getRange('A1').getValue()  

console.log(sheetTitle)
}

    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = sheetTitle
```

`
and in the form.html file I have

```
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
```

When I console.log it, the text I want appears but when I try to link it to my h1 id, then nothing shows up. I'm not sure why it's not populating. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: `document.getElementById` is a client side function not a google apps script server side function.  You need to figure out out to get the info from the Spreadsheet to the html.  You can load it with a google.script.run from a window.onload in your javascript or use scriptlets in an htmlTemplate.